# Modelling Classes based off versioned XSD files

Tags: c#, xml, class, xsd, versioning

I'm currently coding to a standard defined in XML. The standard has provided me with 2 XSD's i must support. with breaking changes in backwards compatibility. My question is a general one in which is the best practice to implement these. I went down the path of using "XSD.EXE" to generate class files to model the XML in a strongly typed manner. That obviously brought me to the conclusion that there is not any way to version class files in C# other then overriding methods but this is not clean for me since the changes are pretty significant in terms of properties ect.

- So my initial idea was to just use standard XML parsing in each versioned processor and not worry about strongly typed models, i write a lot more code( and less clean code ) in the process.
- Second idea was to version my model and processor names that much the xsd version ( a tag in the XML ) so id have a class named "Equipment_1_0" and "Equipment_1_1" and use a factory to return me the proper type to de-serialize as but this seems hacky.

And my final idea was to turn here because these seems like an issue many people would have addressed before. Any insight or resources anyone can point me to in terms of best practices in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using something similar to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx